# Model method isn't returning when called from one HTML template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

```
class Food(models.Model):
    fdc_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('food-detail', args=[str(self.fdc_id)])
```

models.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views, urls
from django.urls import include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('foods/', views.FoodListView.as_view(), name='foods'),
    path('foods/<int:pk>', views.FoodDetailView.as_view(), name='food-detail'),
]
urlpatterns += [
        path('myfoods/',views.FoodsEatenByUser.as_view(), name='my-eaten'),
        ]
```

urls.py

```
class FoodListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):

    model = Food
    context_object_name = 'food_list'
    queryset = Food.objects.filter(name__contains='kale').order_by('calcium').values()[:50]
```

views.py

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Food List</h1>
    {% if food_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for food in food_list %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ food.get_absolute_url }}">{{ food.name }}</a> ({{food.fdc_id}})
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    <ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>There are no foods in the database</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

food_list.html

The food_list page appears how I expect it to but the url returned by get_absolute_url is /catalog/foods

However, if I enter the url manually it will take me to the detail page for the object, where the method does return the correct url.

```
{% extends 'base_generic.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Food View</h1>

<a href="{{ food.get_absolute_url }}">{{ food.name }}</a> ({{food.fdc_id}})
<p>{{ food.name}}</p>


{% for f,v in food.get_fields %}

  
   <p> {{ f }}: {{ v }} </p>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

food_detail.html

In food_detail, the url returned is /catalog/foods/<fdc_id>

Also, the links on the list page did go to the correct detail page at one point, I'm not sure when it stopped working.

I added a function to my Food model that returned "hello world" and the same thing happened, it worked when called in the food_detail template but not the food_list template.

Why is the method not returning in the food_list template?

Comment: Can you please share your `FoodListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** use [**`.values(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values). `.values(…)` returns a `QuerySet` of *dictionaries*. A dictionary does not have a `get_absolute_url` method, hence the error.

You should let Django return *objects*, so:

```
class FoodListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Food
    context_object_name = 'food_list'
    queryset = Food.objects.filter(name__contains='kale').order_by('calcium')[:50]
```